# "Too few positive probabilities" error in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I wrote a code in R, but it produces a silly mistake. The first error is "Too few positive probabilities" and this leads to NAs. Therefore, the code does not work. Can you please take a look and let me know what is wrong? Here are the first 5 rows and the headings of the data (since I do not know how to upload a text file. Please tell me how if you do)

```
year  month day n_cases n_controls  weekd   leapyr
1999    1   1   127 62  6   0
1999    1   2   88  46  7   0
1999    1   3   26  15  1   0
1999    1   4   606 275 2   0
1999    1   5   479 252 3   0
```

and here is the R code

```
 ##########

a<-read.table("e29.txt",header=T)
attach(a)
cases<-a[,4]# fourth column in data "Cases"
data<-cases[1:2555]
weeklydata<-matrix(data,7,365)
y=apply(weeklydata,2,sum)
```

#

```
T<-length(y)
N<-1000
a<-0.98
pfstate<-matrix(0,T+1,N)
pfomega<-matrix(0,T+1,N)
pfphi<-matrix(0,T+1,N)#storge of phi
pfb<-matrix(0,T+1,N)#storge of b
wts<-matrix(0,T+1,N)
wnorm<-matrix(0,T+1,N)

set.seed(046)
pfstate[1,]<-rnorm(N,0,100)#rep(0,N)#
pfomega[1,]<-runif(N,0,1)
pfb[1,]<-runif(N,0,5)
wts[1,]<-rep(1/N,N)


for(t in 2:(T+1)){
##compute means and variances of the particles cloud for sigma and omega

 meanomega<-weighted.mean(pfomega[t-1,],wts[t-1,])
 varomega<-weighted.mean((pfomega[t-1,]-meanomega)^2,wts[t-1,])
 meanb<-weighted.mean(pfb[t-1,],wts[t-1,])
 varb<-weighted.mean((pfb[t-1,]-meanb)^2,wts[t-1,])

##compute the parameters of gamma kernel
 muomega<-a*pfomega[t-1,]+(1-a)*meanomega
 var2omega<-(1-a^2)*varomega
 alphaomega<-muomega^2/var2omega
 betaomega<-muomega/var2omega

 mub<-a*pfb[t-1,]+(1-a)*meanb
 var2b<-(1-a^2)*varb
 alphab<-mub^2/var2b
 betab<-mub/var2b

##1.1 draw the auxiliary indicator varibales
probs<-wts[t-1,]*dpois(y[t-1],exp(pfstate[t-1,]))
auxInd<-sample(N,N,replace=TRUE,prob=probs)

##1.2 draw the values of variances of sigma and omega and delta
pfomega[t,]<-rgamma(N,shape=alphaomega[auxInd],rate= betaomega[auxInd]) 
pfb[t,]<-rgamma(N,shape=alphab[auxInd],rate= betab[auxInd])
pfphi[t,]<-(pfb[t,]-1)/(1+pfb[t,])

##1.3 draw the states
pfstate[t,]<-rnorm(N,mean=pfphi[t,]*pfstate[t-1,auxInd],sd=sqrt(pfomega[t,]))

##compute the weigths
wts[t,]<-exp(dpois(y[t-1],exp(pfstate[t,]),log=TRUE)-
        dpois(y[t-1],exp(pfstate[t-1,auxInd]),log=TRUE))
#print(wts)

wnorm[t,]<-wts[t,]/sum(wts[t,])                 

#print(wnorm)
                       }
### The first error occurs here
Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : 
 too few positive probabilities

ESS<-rep(0,T+1)
ESSthr<-N/2
 for(t in 2:(T+1)){
ESS[t]<-1/sum(wnorm[t,]^2)
if(ESS[t]<ESSthr){
 pfstate[t,]<-sample(pfstate[t,],N,replace=T,prob=wnorm[t,])
    wnorm[t,]<-1/N      
             }
               }
#THe second error occurs here 
#Error in if (ESS[t] < ESSthr) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for people to go through, why not reduce it down to the minimum required to reproduce the error

Comment: Please strip out all the irrelevant code, provide a reproducible data sample, and show us exactly when/where you got an error message.

Comment: I have reduced the code and stated where the errors appear

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be here:

```
probs<-wts[t-1,]*dpois(y[t-1],exp(pfstate[t-1,]))
auxInd<-sample(N,N,replace=TRUE,prob=probs)
```

It looks like your vector of probabilities becomes all `0`s at some point.  This could happen, for example if `y[t-1]` is very large.  For example `dpois(300,3)` evaluates to `0`.

By the way, this problem could be an indication that something is wrong conceptually in your experiment design.  Since I don't know what you are doing, I can't help here.

Anyway, if you are confident that the algorithm is correct, but you want to avoid this error, one solution is to use the `log` form of `dpois`, and then adding a constant, since all that matters for the call to `sample` is relative weights.  Something like this might work:

```
lprobs<-dpois(y[t-1],exp(pfstate[t-1,]),log=T)
lprobs<-lprobs-max(lprobs)
probs<-wts[t-1,]*exp(lprobs)
```

Comment: Still does not work :(